# Scaling an UIImageView with UIViewContentModeTop using CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I have an issue with applying multiple transformations while a maintaining a UIImageView's contentMode.

I have defined an UIImageView with `contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop`. My intention is that applying a scale transformation shouldn't skew the image, but keep the top of the image visible.

Unfortunately, setting the transform, still skews the image:

```
_imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.5);
```

As I understand it, this should scale the image to half the height, effectively clipping the bottom part of the image, however as mentioned, the UIImageView seems to use  `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` and thereby skewing the image.

The reason I use transform and not just frame manipulations is that I also want to apply a rotation to the view.

It might be relevant that I have also set a custom anchorPoint on the layer:

```
_imageView.layer.anchorPoint = (CGPoint){0.2, 0.06};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by not scaling using transform, but instead modifying the bounds rectangle, which is allowed when making transforms. Modifying the size using the bounds rect, correctly uses the contentmode I have set on the view.